# C# method parameters values logging automatization

Tags: c#, logging

I am logging method name and its parameters values as shown below (pseudo code):

```
class TestClass
{
    void Method(int Param1, int Param2, int Param3)
    {
       _logger->AddLogEntry("Method",Param1, Param2, Param3);
      ....
      <some work here>
      ....
    }

    void AnotherMethod(int Param)
   {
       _logger->AddLogEntry("AnotherMethod",Param);

      ....
      <some work here>
      ....
   }
  .....
}
```

I am a bit confused about need to write all parameters manually as input parameters in `AddLogEntry` method. Its probably to forget one or more parameters when signature of loggable method changed.
Is there any way to automate this step. I mean take all values of all parameters of current method. It would be great if I could take also name of the current method and pair `<param name> - <value>`

Comment: You can either write them manually, or preprocess your code before compilation so that a tool writes them out for you, or you can do that at runtime and incur a significant cost on every function call. Your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) for logging operations, it's work by the [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) model.

It's based on attributes and reflection.

To be more specifically, take a look at their [`LogAttribue`](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Patterns_Diagnostics_LogAttribute.htm) documentation.

Here is a simple example from their website for logging:

```
[assembly:  
Log(AttributeTargetTypes="Contoso.Crm.Orders.*", 
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]  

public class OrderFulfillmentService  
{ 
    public bool IsValid( Order order )  
    { 
        if ( order.Lines.Count == 0 ) 
          return false; 

        if ( order.Amount < 0 ) 
          return false; 

        return true; 

    } 
}
```

Comment: just tryed it out. I like it very much, unfortunately logging feature is only available in paid version. 
anyway thank you so much for advice! Now its clear for me what way I should move